# Multiple domains with shared codebase but different data using Django

Tags: django, url

What I'm trying to do is best explained by looking how [wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com) works:

- each blog is assigned to a new subdomain, but users can use their own domain as well. Custom domains could be assigned using a simple web interface
- each blog has its own contents, theme, etc
- all blogs share the same codebase

Is it possible to do the same thing in Django?

I'm not interested in implementing subdomains, but I want the other features.

It is important to me to find a way that domains don't have to be hardcoded in a configuration file in order to work. The dynamic nature of domain assignment makes managing large number of domains possible. It would be ideal if domain matching could be done against a database table.

I use nginx and uwsgi.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it will require more work in Django compared to out-of-the box Wordpress install but will offer you more flexibility.

You might want to take a look at django [sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/?from=olddocs). However I don't think it will be able to do everything you are trying to do.

A more modular system would be for you to write a script which when invoked will bootstrap a new db schema, new virtuelenv, install all necessary things into it, add a site config for the new site to nginx/apache and then restart the nginx/apache. The code can be from the same directories, except since each site will run on it's own virtualenv, it will be much more secure, reliable and fault tolerant. This however as you can see will require some work but I depending on your requirements, it is the most flexible way.

Comment: There are two problems with this approach:  1. I have to restart nginx each time a new domain is added. It will cause lost connections and downtime for all users (not just the website whose domain is being edited). With a lot of domains, this causes a significant problem.  2. If I want to make a change to my codebase, I have to change each and every instance of code which means once for every domain. This approach doesn't seem optimal.

Comment: Completely agree. It however does give a good infrastructure start to be able to scale very well since instead of a script, you can be running a fabric script... But at that point, you need clusters of computers and each web site has to be running on at least two boxes not to have any downtime.

Comment: I am actually looking to do something like this in near future so the fastest and easiest way I though of now is this simple approach. If you figure out anything more elegant, please share.